# $C^\infty_c (K)$ is separable for $K$ compact

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

$C^\infty_c (K)$ is the space of smooth functions supported on $K$ a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}^d$. For simplicity assume $K$ is just a ball centered at the origin. This has the smooth topology in which convergence is uniform convergence of the functon and all derivatives.

Note that convergence in the smooth topology of $C^\infty_c(K)$ is the same as uniform convergence of all derivatives.

I'm trying to show this space is separable. I initially wanted to use polynomials with rational coefficients, as these are countable and dense in $C_c(K)$ with uniform topology. Then using the fundamental theorem of calculus, we can easily show that this set is also dense in the smooth topology.

But the polynomials are not supported on $K$ so this fails. I was thinking about multiplying by a smooth function supported on $K$ that equals $1$ on most of $K$, but then I'm not sure if the fundamental theorem of calculus argument will still work.

So what can I do?

Comment: This is a bit dubious. For example, how would you define smoothness on a general compact set $K$? Or did you actually mean $C_c^\infty(\Bbb R^d)$?

Comment: I think OP by $C^\infty_c (K)$ means all functions in $C^\infty(\Bbb R^d)$ whose supports are contained in $K$.

Comment: Can you explicitly define the norm you put on $C^\infty_c (K)$ ?

Comment: @nonlinearthought This is not a normed space. It is a Fréchet space, though, with a metric which can be taken to be $d(f,g)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty 2^{-k}\wedge\sum_{|\alpha|=k}\|D^\alpha(f-g)\|_\infty$ (where $\wedge$ denotes the minimum of the two sides, and the inner sum is over multi-indices of the specified rank).

Comment: There are many seminorms which generate the smooth topology. I've added the convergence criterion to the question

Comment: @nonlinearthought $\varphi_n \to \varphi$ iff everything is in $C^\infty_c(K)$ and $\lim_{n \to \infty}\sup_x |\partial^\alpha\varphi_n(x) -\partial^\alpha\varphi(x)| = 0$ for every multi-index $\alpha$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll outline one possible answer here. Sorry, no time to make it very detailed.

Start with a bump function: A nonnegative $C^\infty$ function $\rho$ with support inside the unit ball centered at the origin, and integral $1$. Let $\rho_\delta(x)=\delta^{-d}\rho(x/\delta)$. Now the idea is to note that, if $f\in C_c^\infty(K)$ has its support in the interior of $K$ (which is good enough – use a cutoff function), then the convolution $f*\rho_\delta$ is in $C_c^\infty(K)$ when $\delta$ is small enough, and it converges to $f$ as $\delta\to0$. In fact the convergence is uniform, for
$$ f(x)-f*\rho_\delta(x)=\int_{\mathbb{R}^d} \bigl(f(x)-f(x-y)\bigr)\rho_\delta(y)\,dy, $$
so taking absolute values, using the triangle inequality, and noting the uniform continuity of $f$ ensures this is uniformly small when $\delta$ is small.

The identity $D^\alpha(f*\rho_\delta)=(D^\alpha f)*\rho_\delta$ lets us apply the above to all higher derivatives of $f$ as well.

Now limit your attention to *rational* $\delta$, and replace the integral of the convolution with Riemann sums. Conclude (once more using the uniform continuity of $f$) that $f$ (and its higher derivatives, again using the above trick) can be approximated arbitrarily well by linear combinations (with rational coefficients) of functions $\rho_\delta({\cdot}-a)$, with rational $\delta>0$ and $a\in\mathbb{Q}^d$. Since there are a countable number of these functions, we are essentially done.

(**Edited** to supply some more detail.)

Comment: By Linear Combinations, you mean rational linear combination in which scalar coefficients might not be the value of $f$ at some points but enough close to it ?
Still it is  unclear to me, the sequence you made, itself and  all its derivatives are uniformly convergent to $f$ and $D^\alpha(f)$. 

can you please write your proof in more detail when you have time?

Comment: I added a little more detail. Hopefully it helps. And yes, I had forgotten to mention the point about taking linear combinations over the rationals.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't think to use Riemann sums. Now that I think about it, you can probably also embed $K$ into a large enough torus and use the uniform convergence of Fourier series, noting that the Fourier transform is itself decaying rapidly. At least, more rapidly than any polynomial.

Comment: Actually I have one question, You were considering $f$ with support inside some smaller disc than the unit disc. But if $f$ did not have support inside any smaller disc, then how could we still approximate it and all derivatives uniformly? What if the derivatives oscillate rapidly near the boundary? Even multiplying with a cutoff function, how do you know the cutoff function's derivatives won't be crazy?

Comment: Since the function is $C^\infty$ on $\mathbb{R}^d$, all derivatives will go to zero near the boundary. One way to do the cutoff is to make a $C^\infty$ function $\psi_\delta\colon\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ so that $\psi_\delta(x)=0$ when $x<\delta/2$, and $\psi_\delta(x)=x$ when $x\ge\delta$. Then $\psi_\delta\circ f$ approximates $f$, and vanishes near the boundary of $K$.

Answer (score 0):

For simplicity let's assume $K=$ the closed Unit ball in $R^n.$ Let $\lambda_n$ be a sequence of  positive number such that $\lambda_n ‎\nearrow‎ 1.$

Define 
$$A_{n} = \{P : K \overset{smooth}{\longrightarrow} R ~|  P ~\text{is a rational polynomials on}~ B_ {\lambda_n} \text{and } P=0 ~\text{on}~ K\setminus B_{\lambda_{n+1}}   \}$$
This set is well-defined by picking suitable [bump-function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bump_function) (cut-off), we also may assume $A_n$ is countable by selecting only one $P$ satisfying RHS conditions in the set. Clearly $A_{n} \subset C^\infty_c (K).$ we show that $\bigcup_{n \in N} A_n$ is dense in $C^\infty_c (K)$. To end this pick $f \in C^\infty_c (K)$ and $\epsilon > 0.$ One can find enough large $n \in N$ such that first $\sup_{x \in K\setminus B_{\lambda_{n+1}}} |f (x)| \leq \frac{\epsilon}{4} $ and second $\sup_{x \in B_{\lambda_{n+1}}\setminus B_{\lambda_{n}} } |f (x)| \leq \frac{\epsilon}{4}$  (These two are possible since $f$ is close to zero near the boundary of $K$ is  ) Now choose $P \in A_{n}$ such that First $\sup_{x \in  B_{\lambda_{n}}}|f(x) - P (x)| \leq \frac{\epsilon}{4}$ (wirestrass theorem) and Second $\sup_{x \in B_{\lambda_{n+1}}\setminus B_{\lambda_{n}} } |P (x)| \leq \frac{\epsilon}{4}$ ($P$ near boundary of $K$ is close to zero) .  Then

$$ \| f- p \| \leq \sup_{x \in  B_{\lambda_{n}}}|f(x) - P (x)| + \sup_{x \in B_{\lambda_{n+1}}\setminus B_{\lambda_{n}} } |f (x)|+ \sup_{x \in B_{\lambda_{n+1}}\setminus B_{\lambda_{n}} } |P (x)|+\sup_{x \in K\setminus B_{\lambda_{n+1}}} |f (x)-0| \leq \epsilon $$

Comment: But is this enough to show that all derivatives also stay close? I'm not sure if this algebra is closed under taking antiderivatives...

Comment: I didn't notice that all derivative must stay close.  Definitely this argument doesn't work, since after finite taking derivative Polynomials becomes zero.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of $K$ compact, take $K$ bounded and open (clearly $C^\infty_c(K)$ is dense in $C^\infty_c(\overline{K})$)

As you said the set of polynomials is separable and is dense in $C^\infty(\overline{K})$, but the polynomials are not $C^\infty_c(K)$.

Consider a sequence of open sets $\Omega_n \subset \Omega_{n+1} \subset \ldots \subset K$ such that any $\varphi \in C^\infty_c(K)$  has its support contained in one of those $\Omega_n$.

Take $\phi_n \in C^\infty_c(K)$ such that $\phi_n = 1$ on $\Omega_n$.

For any $\varphi \in C^\infty_c(K), \text{supp}(\varphi) \subset \Omega_n$, we have  a polynomial sequence $p_k$ such that $\lim_k p_k = \varphi$ in  $C^\infty(K)$, thus $\lim_k p_k \phi_n = \varphi \phi_n= \varphi$ in  $C^\infty_c(K)$.

Qed $C^\infty_c(K)$ is the closure of those $p \phi_n$ and is separable.

Comment: Polynomials are not dense in $C^\infty (K)$  !

Comment: @nonlinearthought Why do you think that ? $K$ is bounded.

Comment: Note that topology is not sup norm is,  smooth topology. why polynomials are dens in this topology ?

Comment: @nonlinearthought say because the analytic functions are dense in $C^\infty(K)$ (convolution with the gaussians $n^d e^{-\pi n|x|^2}$)